# How to retrieve string from a remote server?

Tags: android, string, textview

I have many strings in my app, but I don't want to store it there because it will just make my  app bigger. Is there anyway to retrieve the strings from the server?

Comment: How many strings are you saving?

Comment: You can make it as a xml & parse the value from it online.

Comment: Can you give me a link for this tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an SQLite database to store these strings?

To answer your question. Yes, it is possible to retrieve the strings from a remote server, provided, you have appropriate code in place at server side to return a specified string (say, using an ID) as XML/JSON..etc.

Once you get the results back, parse the response to get the string. Here is an example code:

```
private String _mStringURL  = "http://yourserver.com/getString.php?string_id=<a unique id>&language=<languagecode>";
url = new URL(statusURL);
URLConnection connection;                       
connection = url.openConnection();          

//Get data and check to see if everything was OK. Set time out to 10 secs.
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(10*1000);          
int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();            

//Proceed if everything went OK in communication.
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document dom = db.parse(in);
Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("string");

//Your code to further parse and access teh data from return XML/JSON goes here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into internationalization solutions for your programming language. Rather than using it to translate your application, you can simply use it to externalize your strings. Just have your program pull down the .mo/.ini (or whatever file your system uses) from the server.

Keep in mind, though, that this is risky. If the user doesn't have an internet connection, your application will be utterly unusable.

What programming language are you using? I can link you to a tutorial.